# Continuous flipping of images in Viewpager android

Tags: android, android-layout

I implemented a Viewpager with viewpager Indicator. Viewpager has ImageViews in its each page. Now I want to continuously flip the Viewpager automatically(Am not supposed to use View flipper).. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance,

Comment: If the answer helps you out, you should accept it to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 handler = new Handler();
 runnable = new Runnable(){
   public void run() {
     handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true); 
  } 
 };
 handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

Comment: ya, now it keeps flipping. Thanks for your help. But even if i minimize the app, the thread keeps on running, resulting in poor programming and in-efficient CPU usage. I have used this code in onCreate. can i stop the thread when i minimize the app and get back it when the app is active.

Comment: in onPause() of your Activity stop the thread by using handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) and in onResume() resume the thread by handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);